# Looking back for instances that fall within a specific time window

Tags: r, time, split, apply

I have the following data set concerning the use of a service. People are allowed to check in and out of the service so there is a entered service date and a left service date. On another occassion further on, they may enter the service again and leave it after some days.

I want to be able to know for each use of the service (represented by a row) by a person, what is the number of times he/she has used the service in the previous year.

#### What I have tried

I computed an service use index to denote the nth time a service has been used. Next I made use of the index to compute the days since the previous service use. From there on I'm stuck. I'm not sure how I should go about looking back.

I am quite stuck and would appreciate any tips on how to proceed. I wanted to use `lapply` to subset each person into its own dataframe but after which how do I look back?

Thanks.

#### Dataset

```
read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/822467/dataset.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

#### To further illustrate what I need

The following is the data from subject 22. The subject has a total of 5 service usage. For each service usage sans the 1st one, I would look back at the 1 year preceding his entry to the service. E.g. For the 2nd usage of the service, I would look at the entry date, which is `14/08/2009`. I would then look at the previous service usage to see how many fall into a window between `15/08/2008 to 14/08/2009`. I would need to do this for all the instances of service usage for every subject.

```
SubID   Entered_Service Left_Service    Service_Usage_Index Days_Since_Last_Service_Use_Ended
22      09/06/2008      13/06/2008      1                   NA
22      14/08/2009      17/08/2009      2                   427
22      21/03/2010      22/03/2010      3                   216
22      25/03/2010      31/03/2010      4                   3
22      21/06/2010      24/06/2010      5                   82
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution but i'd proceed as follows (if I understood correctly your problem):

```
data <- read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/822467/dataset.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
# first, define your dates as dates so you can compare them
strptime(data[,2],format="%d/%m/%Y") -> entry
strptime(data[,3],format="%d/%m/%Y") -> exit
strptime("31/12/2011",format="%d/%m/%Y") -> end
strptime("01/01/2011",format="%d/%m/%Y") -> start
# then select all rows from 2011
data[(entry<=end & entry>=start) | (exit<=end & exit>=start),] -> data2011
# then see how many rows correspond to each user ID
summary(as.factor(data2011$SubID))
```

**Edit**

Based on the same idea, I hope it will do the trick:

```
data <- read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/822467/dataset.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
data[!is.na(data[,1]),]->data
result <- rep(NA,length=nrow(data))

for(i in unique(data$SubID)){
# Loop through each subject
    data[data$SubID==i,]->temp
    if(nrow(temp)>1){
        for(j in 2:nrow(temp)){
            strptime(temp[j,2],format="%d/%m/%Y") -> end
            end - 365*24*3600 -> start
            # There might be a better way to substract a year to a date but I don't know it...
            strptime(temp[,2],format="%d/%m/%Y") -> entry
            strptime(temp[,3],format="%d/%m/%Y") -> exit
            nrow(temp[(entry<end & entry>=start) | (exit<end & exit>=start),]) -> result[data$SubID==i & data[,2]==temp[j,2]]
            }
        }
    }

result -> data$result
```

Comment: apologies, i think i wasn't clear enough on the first try. I've edited my question to better reflect what i need. Thanks for your help though.